# Predicate on enum property - swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enums, nspredicate

i have an array of `Section` objects

```
class Section: NSObject {

    enum SectionType : String {
        case Name = "NAME"
        case Address = "ADDRESS"
        case Phone = "PHONE"
    }
    var type : SectionType = .Name
}
```

i need to apply predicate on `type` property

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.type == %d", SectionType.Name.rawValue)
let filteredArray = (preferenceSections as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate) //CRASH 
if filteredArray.count > 0 {

}
```

App is crashing with `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Mobile.Section 0x7fb120d33c50> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key type.'`, but the section object has `type` property, which is enum of string.

Please help me fixing the issue

Comment: why not use `.filter` instead of predicate?

Comment: yes we can, but just curious to get it done this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says it all. There's no mapping from your enum type to an Objective-C type, which means the property isn't "key value coding-compliant." You'd need to use a simpler `enum : Int` type for this to map automatically.

Comment: I used `.filter` instead of `NSPredicate` as suggested by @Tj3n

Answer (score 0):

use "%@" instead "%d".

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.type == %@", SectionType.Name.rawValue)